# Alphabetic ListView in react-native iOS / Android Performance

Tags: ios, performance, listview, react-native, alphabetical

I've a unique problem , I'm using an offline database to store around 10000 records of Employee Data which we want our Employees to have  available offline, one of the requirements is to show the employee data in Alphabetical order with Sections in ListView similar to Music App in iOS with a Side index of A-Z so the user can jump to a section quickly and scroll through..If I set the InitialListSize to 20 then it works fine but when I try to jump to index B or C or Z it shows nothing , apparently due to ListView still trying to load records
, I'm not able to go beyond A , nothing shows up , If I set the InitialListSize to 10000, it works but now it locks my UI when I switch from 1 screen to another screen and then comeback to the screen containing the listview.
not sure if this is iOS thing or ListView issue, what am I missing or doing wrong.. any help is highly appreciated...
I'm using the following control to 
https://github.com/sunnylqm/react-native-alphabetlistview

Comment: Are you sure a key property is set for every list item?

Comment: Yes, Absolutely sure